# How Golang builtin function "make" achieve the argument length check for different type?

Tags: go

On the document, API shows `make` accepts a Type and a variable-size IntegerType parameter.

```
func make(t Type, size ...IntegerType) Type
```

To make an array, I can pass 3 parameters, such as
`make([]int, 3, 5)`

but when I try to make a map `make(map[int]int, 3, 5)`
it pops `too many arguments to make(map[int]int)` when I compile.

Is this something related to the compiler?
And is it possible to implement this behaviour for my own functions?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler has special knowledge of `make` and other built-in functions.

The compiler enforces the allowed argument count for kind of value that `make` is initializing.  The compiler will not enforce argument counts for user defined functions.  What's more, user defined functions cannot have a type as an argument.

The best you can do is check at runtime:

```
func example(a ArgType, size ...int) returnType {
    if len(size) != 2 {
       panic("expected two size values")
    }
    ...
}
```